# My data-list search form is not working

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I am trying to combine a data-list with actual links to make a auto-complete search form... Well here is my code:

```
<form action="#">
    <input list="results" type="text" placeholder="Search Me ;)">  
</form>
<datalist id="results" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="Home.html">Home</option>
    <option value="Contact.html">Contact</option>
    <option value="Sitemap.html">Sitemap</option>
</datalist>
```

However it does not work.. Any suggestions?

**----NEW UPDATE----**

Is it possible to assign the form onsubmit or action to the selected value in anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work however you don't use a datalist.
Javascript:

```
function checkInput(searchQuery)
{
    if(searchQuery=="Home")
    {
        window.location = "Home.html";
    }
    else if(searchQuery == "Contact")
    {
        window.location = "Contact.html";
    }
    else if(searchQuery == "Sitemap")
    {
        window.location = "Sitemap.html";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("search").submit();
    }
}
```

In order to let this work your form should have an id of 'search'.
**Edit**
Your input a few changes:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Me ;)" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { checkInput(this.value); return false; }"/>
```

Comment: Hmmm... It does not work, but thank you for your time :)

Comment: Is it possible to assign the form onsubmit or action to the selected value in anyway?

Comment: What you can do is run the input through a javascript if statement before submiting. If the input is equal to the values you set, the site doesn't have to search throught the database and can directly direct to the pages.

Comment: How do you propose we do that?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't embed links into a datalist

eg

```
      <option value="home"><a href="home.html">Home</a></option>
```

The dom simply doesn't work that way.

you would need to build the solution yourself using javascript.

I suggest taking a look at http://www.jqueryui.com they probably have something to help you